# how to convert image to text in C#

Tags: c#, ocr

In one of my project I need to convert image to text. 
After googling found [Tessaract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) can do this. But somehow I cant use it in my application. So besides "Tessaract Engine" , is there any alternative way to convert image to text ?
Plz help.

Comment: `But somehow I cant use it in my application` Why not? What error do you get?

Comment: What do you mean by convert image to text? Do you mean you have a picture of, say, a word and you need to turn that into that word as text or do you mean that you have to turn each small area of the image into a letter that roughly corresponds to the tone of the image so that you are turning out something that, when looked at from far enough away, it looks kind-of like the original picture?

Comment: Given the mention of tessaract software, I would wager it's about converting a scanned page of text into full blown strings/characters, just like some scanner software does when scanning to make searchable/selectable PDFs.

Comment: Why don't you just search the web for .NET OCR libraries?  I'm sure there are plenty of good ones out there.

Comment: My requirement is like if I am having a bmp file in which some text is written, then I need to fetch that text

Answer (score 3):

If convert your image to binary could help, I give you the code. I think you could transform into base64 to manage your image as a string but it's larger than the image.

```
public byte[] ImageToByte(Image image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format){
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Convert Image to byte[]
                image.Save(ms, format);
                byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
                return imageBytes;
            }
        }
```

If you want to convert it to base64 let me know.

Hope it helps

Comment: I think OP wants OCR - as that's what Tessaract is.

Comment: My requirement is like if I am having a bmp file in which some text is written, then I need to fetch that text

Answer (score 2):

Asprise OCR SDK for C#
http://www.pcworld.com/downloads/file/fid,141881-order,4/description.html